# How to use gas price for faster transaction in erc20 transafer event?

Tags: erc-20, web3j, java

**I'm trying to provide a customised gas price for faster transaction ,how can achieve that ?**

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService("http://"));
    ERC20 javaToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress, web3, creds, new DefaultGasProvider());
    TransactionReceipt receipt = javaToken.transfer("0x6D594E3C913059e3AB2b3CEAc37b3050c689Da10", value).send();
```

Comment: That depends on a lot of things: Are you public network ? Is it POW or POA ? If not on public network then what are the miners' configuration ?

Comment: I'm asking for java's Erc20 class functionality to provide gas fees for transaction.,

Comment: @FlorianCastelain its on test network of Ganache ,I'm exploring this library for educational purpose.

Answer (score 1):

you need a new class that implements the StaticGasProvider (the value of gaslimit is just an example, you don't usually need that much for a transfer transaction)

```
import org.web3j.tx.Contract;
import org.web3j.tx.gas.StaticGasProvider;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class GasProvider extends StaticGasProvider {
    public static final BigInteger GAS_LIMIT = BigInteger.valueOf(3_500_000); 
    public GasProvider(BigInteger gas_price) {
        super(gas_price, GAS_LIMIT);
    }
}
```

And then

```
ERC20 javaToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress, web3, creds, new GasProvider(<your-gas-price-in-wei-as-biginteger>));
```

Comment: How does this decrease "transaction time" ?

Comment: you cannot decrease it, you can only give the miner more money so they pick it first and mine it before other transaction in their waiting-list

Comment: Thanks @MajdTL ,but if i want to provide gas price through an api call or pass it as an parameter then ? any suggetion?

Comment: I edit the answer for you, it is pure java and has nothing to do with ethereum and web3j

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/31683/majd-tl can you please check https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/140299/java-lang-runtimeexception-error-processing-transaction-request-insufficient-f