# java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: erc-20, web3j, android

My contract is already deployed on `BSC testnet`.

```
val web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService("https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/"))
val keyPair = ECKeyPair.create(BigInteger("1234"))
val credential = Credentials.create(keyPair)
val contractGasProvider: ContractGasProvider = DefaultGasProvider()

val greeter = Greeter.load(BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR, web3j, credential, contractGasProvider)
val greeterErc20 = GreeterErc20.load(BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_ERC20, web3j, credential, contractGasProvider)

    // setGasProvider is added because of getting below error
    // java.lang.RuntimeException: Error processing transaction request: transaction underpriced
    greeter.setGasProvider(object : DefaultGasProvider() {
        override fun getGasPrice(contractFunc: String): BigInteger {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(10000000000)
        }

        override fun getGasLimit(contractFunc: String): BigInteger {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(4300000)
        }
    })

    greeterErc20.setGasProvider(object : DefaultGasProvider() {
        override fun getGasPrice(contractFunc: String): BigInteger {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(10000000000)
        }

        override fun getGasLimit(contractFunc: String): BigInteger {
            return BigInteger.valueOf(4300000)
        }
    })

    val result = web3j.ethGetBalance(Pref.user!!.mkey, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
    Log.e("Balance", result.balance.toString())
    // result.balance.toString() = 1400000000000000000

    val balance = Convert.fromWei(result.balance.toString(), Convert.Unit.ETHER)
    Log.e("Balance", balance.toString())
    // balance Converted = 1.4

    val block: EthBlock.Block = web3j.ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, false).send().block
    val gasLimit = block.gasLimit
    Log.e("gasLimit", gasLimit.toString())
    // gasLimit = 50000000

    // After this I am calling ownerOf method and its working as expected
    try {
        val greeting: Future<String> = greeter.ownerOf(BigInteger.valueOf(nftUrl)).sendAsync()
        val ownerIdStr: String? = greeting.get()
        Log.e("ownerId", "" + ownerIdStr)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    //Then I am calling allowance and its also working as expected
    try {
        val greeting: Future<BigInteger> = greeterErc20?.allowance(Pref.user?.mkey, BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR)!!.sendAsync()
        val allowance: BigInteger? = greeting.get()
        Log.e("allowance", "" + allowance)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    // allowance = 0

    // If allowance == 0 then I am trying to call approve method
    try {
        val approveAmount = BigInteger.valueOf(400000000000000000)
        val greeting: Future<TransactionReceipt> = greeterErc20?.approve(BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR, approveAmount)!!.sendAsync()
        val transactionReceipt: TransactionReceipt? = greeting.get()
        Log.e("approve transactionReceipt", "" + transactionReceipt?.transactionHash)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    // Here I am getting below error
    // Error processing transaction request : insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Comment: When you are calling the approve method you are using "credential" as the signer of the transaction. "credential" is generated in the code and has no balance. The other calls are readOnly and cost no gas

Comment: can you please explain me in details

Comment: you need to use your account that have balance when you are loading the contract probably Greeter.load(...somewhere here instead of credential...)

Comment: Means here val greeter = Greeter.load(BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR, web3j, credential, contractGasProvider) need to change credentials

Comment: Its my metamask public address

Comment: BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_10COLOR -  Contract address BuildConfig.CONTRACT_ADDRESS_ERC20 - ERC20 contract address Pref.user!!.mkey - metamak public address

Comment: okay you need the private key of that account. and using this private key you can generate a keypair and use it when you load the contract.

Comment: try to use this method: Credentials.create(String privateKey, String publicKey))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140983/discussion-between-majd-tl-and-pavya).